# Load table values into objects variable without mapping

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have the following data model

```
Product: id, description, price
ProductExtraField: id, name
ProductExtraFieldData: product_id, extra_field_id, value
```

I want to use this datamodel so users of my application can add extra properties to a product on the fly. Let's say the add the property 'Color'. When they do so a row will be created in the `ProductExtraField` table with a value like this: *6, 'Color'*. Now the can add values for this property to there products. When the do so a new row will be created in the `ProductExtraFieldData` table with a value like this: *4, 6, 'Green'*. Now I want to represent this model in a class called `Product`. I use the following code:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity @Table(name="product") **/  
class Product

    public function __construct() {
        $this->extraFieldData = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->extraField = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    private $id;
    /** @Column(name="description", type="string") **/
    private $description;
    /** @Column(name="price", type="float") **/
    private $price;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductExtraFieldData", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var extraFieldData[]
     **/
    protected $extraFieldData = null;

     /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductExtraField", mappedBy="??????")
     * @var extraField[]
     **/
    protected $extraField = null;
```

Offcourse the last couple of lines are not correct. I don't know how to load this data. I want the names of the extra fields to be available with every product. I think `$extraField` should even be static. How can I configure Doctrine to load these values? Persisting the `$extraField` values from the `Product` class is not requirement.

Comment: Do you need those fields _inside_ product body? You can inject a `ExtraFieldList` into products in your controller [assuming you are in a MVC environment], or even in repository methods.

Comment: I don't want to think of the extra fields in the controller. I just want to load the product in the controller and it should have the extraFields filled. I have created a magic __get and __set method so I can just use `$product->Color = 'Green'` in the code. This works right now but I have the configure the ExtraField property right now. I want it to be filled with values from the database. Maybe I need to create my own repository but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Well I now how to create a repository but I don't want to redefine all the find methods. Maybe there is an event I can listen to, so when a product is loaded I can insert the ExtraFields?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a structure like the following:

**Product**

- id
- description
- etc...

**ProductExtraField**

- product_id
- extra_field_id
- value

**ExtraField**

- id
- label
- (anything else? type?)

So your `Product` will have a OneToMany mapping on `ProductExtraField`, which will have a `ManyToOne` mapping to `ExtraField`. Allowing you to use code such as...

```
$extraValues = array();
foreach ($product->getExtraFields() as $productExtraField) {
    $extraValues[$productExtraField->getExtraField()->getLabel()] = $productExtraField->getValue();
}

// builds array such as array('colour' => 'blue', 'size' => 'small)
```

Comment: Yes, I had this kind of construction already. Only problem is when the property doesn't exist for the product. How do I add that property and its value?

Comment: Sorry, I did notice that...your mapping makes it look as though you've got a different structure. If you define the mapping of the 3 entities as I described, then you'll be able to create the relevant form types to use as required. Clue: your ProductType will contain a collection type of ProductExtraFieldTypes. [See Collection field type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Comment: The structure is as you describe above. Problem is when the product doesn't have any ProductExtraFields. When you want to create a new one how do I find which extra_field_id I need. There is no list of available ExtraField in the product class.

Comment: I think I need some sort of strange many to many relation between `product` and `extrafield` without a join table. So all products have all extrafields...